# How can I send tasks to specific queues without execute in Celery?

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

I've tried sending tasks with `send_task` and `apply_async`, it's works, but I don't want execute tasks in subprocess, I just want send it to broker. I used `delay` but I can't specify the queue, any tip?

I am expecting send a task without executing

Answer (score 1):

You can specify which queue tasks will be sent to with the following code:

```py
your_celery_app.conf.task_routes = {
        your_task_name: {'queue': your_queue_name}
    }
```

`your_task_name` is the task name that is printed under `[tasks]` when you launch the worker, for example `my_app.tasks.my_task.my_task`. `your_queue_name` is the name of the queue, usually specified with the `-Q` command line parameter when launching the worker.

For more information, please see https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/latest/userguide/routing.html